# Filtrar un DataTable con espacio en la columna en VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable

Estoy intentando filtrar un DataTable  con la siguiente instrucción:

```
Dim filtro As String = "ID  like '%" & txtID.Text & "%'"
dt1.DefaultView.RowFilter = filtro
DGV1.DataSource = dt1.DefaultView
```

Hasta ahí el código funciona, pero tengo varias tablas que tienen un espacio en el nombre de columna, y lo he intentado colocar ese nombre dentro de llaves, comillas simples y sin resultado.

**Intento #1**

```
Dim filtro As String = "EMP ID  like '%" & txtEMPID.Text & "%'"
dt2.DefaultView.RowFilter = filtro
DGV1.DataSource = dt2.DefaultView
```

**Intento #2**

```
Dim filtro As String = "[EMP ID]  like '%" & txtEMPID.Text & "%'"
dt2.DefaultView.RowFilter = filtro
DGV1.DataSource = dt2.DefaultView
```

**Intento #3**

```
Dim filtro As String = "'EMP ID'  like '%" & txtEMPID.Text & "%'"
dt2.DefaultView.RowFilter = filtro
DGV1.DataSource = dt2.DefaultView
```

Al ejecutar la búsqueda en la tabla, da error que no encuentra la columna ID o [EMP ID] dependiendo que intento se ejecutó.

Colocar un subguión para que sea una sola palabra no es una opción, se tiene varias tablas con espacios en el nombre y se deben filtrar precisamente por ese nombre.

Talvez les pasó algo similar y encontraron la forma de filtrar columnas con espacio en el nombre?

Comment: Debiera funcionar encerrando el nombre entre corchetes. ¿Qué mensaje de error da si aplicas el _Intento #2_?

Comment: Da el error, no se encuentra la columna [EMP ID]

Comment: Suponiendo que es la primera columna, que pasa si pones `"[" & dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName + "] like '%" & txtEmpID.Text & "%'"`

Comment: Lo he probado invocando a nombre de columna  y me sale  que la columna ID no se encuentra.

Comment: se puede hacer esto? `"select dt2.column(0),  dt2.column(1) from datatable where emp_id like '%" & txtemp.text & "%'"`
mostrar ciertos campos de una tabla al filtrarlos, tipo sql statement